# Post and Get a variable using yesod server

Tags: haskell, yesod

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var store = undefined

app.post("/", function(req, res){
  store = req.body
})

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.send(store)
} 
app.listen(some_port_num)
```

This is a simple nodejs/express server application which stores the http request body in a global variable and sends the same variable as responsse on a get request.

How to write this code in yesod/haskell. I don't know how to use global/module-scoped variables in haskell/yesod. And, is there any other way to share variables between two  functions in haskell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using global constants is trivial in Haskell: you just write `foo = bla` somewhere (preferrably with a signature `foo :: FooType`). `foo` can then be used anywhere in your module (or even outside, if you export it).

*Global variables* OTOH aren't really possible in Haskell, as such. For the most part, that's a good thing because global state tends to lead to *lots* of bugs. Often when programmers think about global variables, it turns out global constants would be just fine, or otherwise the mutable state should better be re-written as explicit parameters.

Sometimes however you pretty much do need state variables. In Yesod in particular, there's a place where you can store them sort-of globally: *the Yesod*. That is the data structure that your web application has as its “basement”. For instance, you may have

```
data YourYesod = YourYesod {
      ...
      , reqStore :: IORef RequestBody   -- IORef basically means, it's variable
                                        -- in the imperative sense.
      ...
      }

mkYesod "YourYesod" [parseRoutes| ... |]
```

The Yesod can be accessed from anywhere in the `Handler` etc. monads, e.g. in

```
getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    ...
    yourYesod <- getYesod           -- gain "access" to the Yesod
    storeS <- liftIO $ readIORef (reqStore yourYesod)  -- look up the variable state
    ...
    liftIO $ writeIORef (reqStore yourYesod) newStoreS -- write new state
    ...
```

At the beginning of the program, the `reqStore` will need to be initialised, by something like

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   ...
   initReqStore = newIORef emptyRequest
   ...
   warp 3000 $ YourYesod ... initReqStore ...
```

Before doing it this way, think about whether the `store` variable really needs to be that global. The Yesod is pretty much the most global scope you have for stuff like that; that means also danger of those typical bugs like in procedural languages. If the variable is only used within one handler, you might as well just introduce it locally, like

```
               do
                 ...
                 store <- newIORef emptyRequest
                 appPost "/" $ \req res -> do
                       liftIO $ writeIORef store $ body req
                 appGet "/" $ \req res -> do
                       storedReq <- liftIO $ readIORef store
                       send res storedReq
```

Comment: hi leftaroundabout, thanks for spending a lot of time on this question... i have this doubt `storeS <- liftIO $ readIORef (reqStore yourYesod)` Vs `storedReq <- readIORef store`. Why is the `liftIO` function used in the first case?

Comment: My mistake, `liftIO` is actually needed in both cases. Why it's needed: all those “mutable variables” are really just references; the references themselves live in the Yesod or the local scope, but the actual mutable _content_ they're pointing to is in the messy general `IO` monad, and Haskellers generally avoid exposing that. Yesod's monads _can_ access `IO`, but only by explicitly lifting.